# Show unit movable range within 1 turn?

Tags: civilization-5

Is there any option to enable the display of unit movable range within 1 turn?

I watched one YouTube video and saw that it displayed on his game like this but somehow I cannot find this in the Game Options.

[image: pic]

Comment: Perfect visual aid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold right-click (movement button), IIRC.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to holding down the right mouse button, the <kbd>M</kbd> key will toggle the single-move radius of a unit.

There's also a button on the unit command panel that looks like a bunch of hexes with an arrow overlaid, this will do the same thing.  (<kbd>M</kbd> is a shortcut for this command)

It's not shown in your screenshot, but pressing <kbd>G</kbd> will bring up the hex grid, which can be useful in determining how far apart things are.